# Split a string without separator

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, c#-4.0

I have a string variable with value
    "abcdefghijklmnop".

Now I want to split the string into string array with, say, three characters (the last array element may contain fewer) in each array element from the right end.

I.e.,
    "a"
    "bcd"
    "efg"
    "hij"
    "klm"
    "nop"

What is the easiest and simplest way to do this?? (Both Visual Basic and C# code is welcome)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
var input = "abcdefghijklmnop";
var result = new List<string>();
int incompleteGroupLength = input.Length % 3;
if (incompleteGroupLength > 0)
    result.Add(input.Substring(0, incompleteGroupLength));
for (int i = incompleteGroupLength; i < input.Length; i+=3)
{
    result.Add(input.Substring(i, 3));
}
```

It gives the expected output of:

```
"a"
"bcd"
"efg"
"hij"
"klm"
"nop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex time!!

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^(.{1,2})??(.{3})*$");

var matches = rx.Matches("abcdefgh");

var pieces = matches[0].Groups[1].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).Concat(matches[0].Groups[2].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value)).ToArray();
```

`pieces` will contain:

```
"ab"
"cde"
"fgh"
```

(Please, don't use this code! It is only an example of what can happen when you use a regular expression + LINQ.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works - wrapped up into a string extension function.

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExts
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> ReverseCut(this string txt, int cutSize)
        {
            int first = txt.Length % cutSize;
            int taken = 0;

            string nextResult = new String(txt.Take(first).ToArray());
            taken += first;
            do
            {
                if (nextResult.Length > 0)
                    yield return nextResult;

                nextResult = new String(txt.Skip(taken).Take(cutSize).ToArray());
                taken += cutSize;
            } while (nextResult.Length == cutSize);

        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
            textBox2.Text = "";
            var txt = textBox1.Text;

            foreach (string s in txt.ReverseCut(3))
                textBox2.Text += s + "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... here is yet another way I arrived at:

```
private string[] splitIntoAry(string str)
{
    string[] temp = new string[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)str.Length / 3)];
    while (str != string.Empty)
    {
        temp[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)str.Length / 3) - 1] = str.Substring(str.Length - Math.Min(str.Length, 3));
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - Math.Min(str.Length, 3));
    }
    return temp;
}
```